# User Authentication with CrudAdminGenerator

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, silex

I'm using https://github.com/jonseg/crud-admin-generator to generate a simple back-end for database operations. However, I want to make it so that only an admin user can use the page.

I can't seem to find a good tutorial that is compatible with this framework. I've looked at Symfony and Silex tutorials, but neither one seem to be 'compatible'. This framework doesn't seem to have those files..... Is there a tutorial / something that can help me get started with this? Is there an easy/safe way to lock down some pages in PHP that is compatible with this framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a property in the firewall, named "security.access_rules"
that add the path and the role and that'll make it so you can lock down certain routes.